# Why is npm saying PhantomJS not found on PATH, when it is on PATH?

Tags: phantomjs, environment-variables, npm-install

Due to the network security configuration at our company, I have manually downloaded and extracted phantomjs:

[image: Extracted path]

I have added this path to my PATH *user* environment variable:

[image: Environment variables]

c:\users\hb31996\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts;C:\Users\HB31996\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User;C:\Users\HB31996\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts;C:\Users\HB31996\PhantomJS\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe;

Yet when I am running `npm install` for a project on this dev machine, I get the error "PhantomJS not found on PATH".  And if I try to simply type the command, "phantomjs", 'phantomjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What have I got wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the executable file from the **PATH**, e.g. to simply "C:\Users\HB31996\PhantomJS\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin". **PATH** should point to a containing folder.